# How to verify a user with its username and password?

Tags: salesforce

Because in Salesforce, I cannot directly use password to verify a user. So how to do with this?

Maybe this is an external user or an internal one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question. You could use password for sign-in, or use single sign-on or lightning login for password-less sign-in.

Comment: I mean I want to use Apex to verify username and password.